# Cloud Composer does not allow configuration override in one Airflow instance, but it allows in another

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-composer

We are using multiple *Cloud Composer* instances `composer-1.14.2-airflow-1.10.14` in a single Google Cloud project. We experience that what works in one Composer instance, does not work in another.

We've overridden the `auth_backend` setting from value `airflow.api.auth.backend.deny_all` to `airflow.api.auth.backend.default` for the Airflow configuration, because we want to trigger DAGs over HTTP via *IAP* (https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf). We've set this in the Composer's Airflow configuration overrides section. The `airflow.cfg` contains this:

```
[api]
auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.default
```

This setting works in two Composer instances, but does not work in the third one. In *Airflow UI / Admin / Configuration* page the content of the `airflow.cfg` has the correct value `airflow.api.auth.backend.default` for the third instance but the *Running Configuration* shows `airflow.api.auth.backend.deny_all`. For the other two instances the *Running Configuration* shows the correct value `airflow.api.auth.backend.default`.

We've tried to restart the composer by adding a new configuration value and by restarting the nodes of the GKE cluster but the configuration is still not used.

This page writes that `api-*` configurations are blocked for override (although the other two Composers can accept it): https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/airflow-configurations

**Questions**:

- If the overrides for these settings `api-*` are blocked, how is this allowed in the other two Composer instances and how is not on the third one?
- If the overrides for these settings `api-*` are NOT blocked, then why is it in the documentation at all and why the DAG triggering documentation writes that it should be enabled for IAP?
- How could we force the third Composer to use the configuration what other two instances allow us to use?
- What are we doing wrong?

Comment: I think this document hasn't been updated and `api-` is not blocked any more. The change was done around November 2020 in this area and since than it's possible to override this part as well ([relase notes](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/release-notes#November_09_2020)). I would double check why its not possible too update this value, as there should be no issue with that. Is there any error when you tired to update it?

Comment: @vitooh Where could I check exactly if there is any error? (Composer? Kubernetes? Airflow?) Is there any log about this on Composer's side? The Monitoring UI of the Composer does not show anything. The value is set in Composer, and in Airflow's cfg file, but the runtime configuration does not show the new value.

Comment: It's really hard to say anything. I noticed that, if you assign wrong key/value pair it does not show any errors, so first I would review if there are no typo in it. Otherwise I suggest to fill the bug ([here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/getting-support#file_bugs_or_feature_requests) according to docs).